# Russian Roulette (Redux!)

Tags: strategy, probability, game-theory

You are challenged to a game of Russian roulette with a six-chamber revolver, but you and your opponent are allowed to change the outcome of the game in different ways. Here's how the game will proceed:

- You may fill any of the chambers with a bullet. You must place at least 1 bullet into the revolver, but you have enough bullets to fill the entire revolver
- After you have chosen the configuration, your opponent may do 1 of 2 things:

  - Choose whether to go first or second
  - Move a single bullet, and flip a coin to decide whether they go first or second
- After the opponent action is complete, the cylinder is spun exactly once
- You both continue to fire the revolver until one player can no longer continue

Going "first" means that person is the first target of the revolver. Find a) the strategy/strategies that maximize(s) the odds of survival for yourself, and b) the corresponding strategy/strategies that maximize(s) the odds of survival for your opponent. Additionally, show that your opponent can bound your maximum probability of survival to 50%, and that you can bound your opponent's maximum probability of survival to 50%.

Comment: is it allowed to give her anxiolytics just before starting the "choose whether to go" part?

Comment: It's not allowed to interact with the other person. All you may do is choose whether each chamber has/does not have a bullet. The opponent is similarly forbidden from interacting with you. All they may do is choose first/second, or move a bullet and flip for first/second.

Comment: sorry, this is just my english: moving a bullet means removing one bullet while seeing the whole cyliinder load, moving a bullet over to different hole, or turning a single bullet turn on the cylinder?

Comment: Does the opponent get to see the configuration I chose before deciding which action to take?

Comment: @Bass Yes - they can look in the gun as they choose which bullet to move. They will not shoot themselves accidentally while looking into the gun.

Comment: Of course they get to see the configuration when they move the bullet. But what about looking before choosing their action?

Comment: @Bass Yes, they can do this.

Comment: @balazs.com It means moving a bullet over to a different hole (if possible).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You always have a simple 50% strategy:

> put 1 bullet in the gun.

Whatever the opponent chooses, there are exactly 3 good spin results and 3 bad ones for you.

Your opponent always has a simple 50+% strategy:

> Go second.

Doing otherwise is always worse, or equal at best; there are no possible bullet configurations where there are more than 3 "good" spin results for the player going first.

Since your opponent always has a 50+% strategy, it's impossible for you to have better than 50% strategy, so these are best strategies for both.

Comment: I may have made this question too easy *facepalm*...

Comment: I was thinking the other way around; always put 6 bullets for a simple 50% strategy

Comment: @Avi not at all, there are a lot of interesting variations that give rise to plenty of interesting strategies, and the opponent's strategy didn't feel at all trivial to find.

Comment: @Alex isn't that an automatic loss though? The opponent would choose to go second.

Comment: @Bass Ok, that's good to know :)

Comment: If psychological reason is involved, yeah, but if that's the case for your answer you could always put that 1 bullet on the 2nd chamber such that the second shot always fires the bullet (to increase your chance of survival)?

Comment: @Alex see the third major bullet point, the cylinder is spun after the opponent's choice. (Oops, OP had made a small error there, the barrel of a revolver isn't spinnable. Fixed now.)

Comment: @Bass Oh right, yes i missed that part, so it does not matter which chamber.  And yes, the cylinder hah